# Ruby bindings for Qt gui application

Tags: ruby, qt, binding

How to create a Qt GUI applications with the ability to access it from the ruby script.

Example:

```
require 'myQt'
myapp=myQt.new
myapp.startQtGuiApp
myapp.setValue('TextField1',45)
value=myapp.getValue('TextField2')
```

Comment: What do you mean "with the ability to access it from the ruby script?"

Answer (score 2):

I assume you're looking for [ruby-qt bindings](http://techbase.kde.org/Development/Languages/Ruby)? There are a few links to tutorials there, as well.